# ASP.NET Membership Provider: Defining a foreign key to aspnet_Users.UserName

Tags: asp.net-membership, foreign-keys, sql-server-express, uniqueidentifier

I'd like to setup a foreign key to a default membership table but I'm getting an error when trying to define it.  I'm using the default aspnet_Users table and also my own Posts table.  I'm trying to setup the tables as follows:

aspnet_Users

- UserId (PK) uniqueidentifier
- UserName nvarchar(256)

Posts

- PostID (PK) int
- UserName (FK -> aspnet_Users.UserName) nvarchar(256)

However, when I try to set this up using the VS 2010 designer, it gives me the following error:

```
The columns in table 'aspnet_Users' do not match an existing primary key
or unique constraint.
```

Is this not working because `aspnet_Users.UserName` isn't a part of the PK for `aspnet_Users`?  I've tried to change the table to include that as part of the PK (I think that makes it a composite key?) but it's telling me to delete the relationships first before I can do it.  Being as I don't know what relationships the default membership tables define, I'd rather find out more before going that route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is fully describing the situation - you're trying to use a non-key field inside a foreign key constraint.  You suggest trying to create a composite key to get around this issue, which would work, but why wouldn't you simply use the existing primary key?

The UserID field is a uniqueidentifier PK, so it is already configured for use in a FK.  And, you'd be utilizing normalization, so that rather than storing (up to) 256 bytes per Username on each row, you'd only be storing the uniqueidentifier (16 bytes).

Comment: I forgot to answer my own question as I asked this rather a long time ago.  Instead of self-answering, I will accept your answewr as it is correct.  My initial concern came from the idea of using the uniqueidentifier in URLs and any possible performance and readability problems that would arise from that.  I'm used to using integers as PKs to pass around so it was something I didn't really understand and a lot of my concerns were based on misconceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to combine it with ApplicationID as well. UserID is not unique except when combined with the application ID.

Comment: Whilst your answer is correct, I've decided to mark Dave's as the answer because his comments accurately reflect my misconceptions at the time.  Thank you for your answer.